# can i use "AND" to where in connectOrCreate for prisma?

Tags: node.js, apollo, prisma

i want to make new holding. there are two cases.

1. there are no product, no account.
2. there are one product, account.

so i use connectOrCreate!. I want to find accountNum with userId and accountNumber
so i use AND in where. but there are error.

Unknown arg `AND` in data.accountNum.connectOrCreate.where.AND for type AccountNumberWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean `id`? Available args

```
 const holding = await client.holding.create({
          data: {
            holdingNum,
            accountNum: {
              connectOrCreate: {
                where: { AND: [{ userId: loggedInUser.id }, { accountNumber }] },
                create: {
                  accountNumber,
                  user: {
                    connect: {
                      id: loggedInUser.id,
                    },
                  },
                  org: {
                    connect: {
                      orgCode,
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            product: {
              connectOrCreate: {
                where: {
                  prodCode,
                },
                create: {
                  prodCode,
                  prodName,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        });

model AccountNumber {
  id         Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  org        Organization @relation(fields: [orgId], references: [id])
  orgId      Int
  user       User         @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId     Int
  accountNum String
  holdings   Holding[]
}

model Holding {
  id           Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  accountNum   AccountNumber @relation(fields: [accountNumId], references: [id])
  accountNumId Int
  product      Product       @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId    Int
  holdingNum   Int
  evalAmt      Int?
}

model Product {
  id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  prodName String
  prodCode String    @unique
  posts    Post[]
  holdings Holding[]
  proposes Propose[]

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not need the AND :

```
accountNum: {
    connectOrCreate: {
        where: {  userId: loggedInUser.id ,  accountNumber  },
        ...
 }
```

Comment: This is correct, the AND is implicit when passing multiple conditions in the `where` clause.